# Pulley inertia moment of inertia

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, string

Considering a pulley with some mass, or some friction, how can its inertia (or moment of inertia) influence the tension on 1 rope? Which part of the rope is influenced? Before or after the pulley?

Comment: You can find out if you plot free body diagram for pulley and rope separately.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is the difference in tension between the ropes on either side of the pulley.

So you will have $(T_2-T_1) R = I_{\text {pulley}}\alpha$ where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the tensions on either side of the pulley, $R$ is the radius of the pulley, $I_{\text {pulley}}$ the moment of inertia of the pulley and $\alpha$ the angular acceleration of the pulley.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the rope rolls without slipping about a frictionless pully, α = a/R where a is the acceleration of objects attached to the ends of the rope (one object moves up and the other down).